# Angular 6 while I trying to render the same image on 2 separate canvas elements

Tags: javascript, angular, image, typescript

What I get is the image is rendered on the second canvas only
but I want the same image to render on both canvases

### This screenshot shows that the image is rendered only on the second canvas

[image]

### HTML component

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <canvas #canvas1 id="ctx1" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid dodgerblue;"></canvas>
  <canvas #canvas2 id="ctx2" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #83ff1e;"></canvas>
</div>
```

### Typescript component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('canvas1') canvas1: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('canvas2') canvas2: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = '../../../assets/img/lena_color.png';

    const width = 500;
    const height = 500;

    const canvas1: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas1.nativeElement;
    const ctx1: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas1.getContext('2d');

    const canvas2: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas2.nativeElement;
    const ctx2: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas2.getContext('2d');

    console.log(ctx1);
    console.log(ctx2);


    this.drawImage(ctx1, img);
    this.drawImage(ctx2, img);

  }


  drawImage(ctx, img) {
    img.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
  }


}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're using the same `Image` object. Try having 2 separate objects i.e. `let img1 = new Image()` and `let img2 = new Image()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define two `Image` objects instead of re-using the same one.

Comment: I need to wait 9 min before I approve your answer Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help! :)